# BLE 4.2 LE Secure Connection

Tags: bluetooth

I am looking at getting the most secure connection between two BLE devices without an I/O capabilities but I am slightly confused by what is going on.

So without I/O capabilities the highest security I can use is **Security mode 1 and Security level 'Unauthenticated pairing with encryption'.**

However I understand with BLE 4.2 there is the ECDH implementation (LE Secure) to protect against MITM attacks. However I can only see this option with ***Security mode 1 and 'Authenticated LE Secure Connections pairing with encryption***... but this requires I/O capabilities.

However from what I can see implementing the ECDH is specifically for a situation where you have an insecure channel, i.e. no I/O capabilities. Does this mean that with Security mode 1 and security level 'Unauthenticated pairing with encryption' I am using the ECDH with MITM protection?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unauthenticated pairing with encryption is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks by virtue of being unauthenticated. The use of ECDH does not protect from active MITM attacks, only from passive monitoring. It is a [misconception](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/91706/106285) to believe that ECDH (or any other key exchange mechanism) on its own can protect against such attacks. [Another answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/141947/106285) explains how ECDH protects against only passive attacks, but is never able to protect from an active attack such as an MITM.

- **Unauthenticated pairing without encryption** does not protect from any attack.
- **Unauthenticated pairing with encryption** protects only from passive attacks.
- **Authenticated pairing with encryption** protects from both passive *and* active attacks.