# Bluetooth 5 - is a pass key enough?

Tags: bluetooth

So far I understood that from Bluetooth 4.2 onwards the Pass Key method is safer due to pre-shared public keys and a 128-bit encryption key. After this pairing process occurs, is the link between the two devices kept encrypted? Meaning that if users sniff data transfer between the two devices they can't see the actual data.

My device uses Bluetooth 5.0 and so I should not be concerned with the Pass Key method not being safe I think. Furthermore should the link between the two devices remain encrypted this would already be a secure measure. Should I be concerned with other security threats?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't be worried. 4.2 Bluetooth devices use Long Term Key to encrypt the data trasmission between them. The generation of Long Term Key are based on Diffie-Hellman. The generation of that key occurs after devices exchange public key and pair.

Comment: This is a misconception. Please read this answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/190607/127837