# Bluetooth security

Tags: encryption, sniffing, bluetooth

How secure is it to use Bluetooth handsfree?

- Can't someone eavesdrop the signals and listen to the conversation?
- Does encryption in Bluetooth secure the information?
- Can I use anyother tool to secure more the Bluetooth I use?

Comment: SDR is not what you would use to eavesdrop

Comment: If you are not using RTL-SDR, then how?

Comment: @just_learning RTL-SDR is *not* the right tool for this. Generally the RTL chips max out at about 1.7GHz, while BT uses 2.4GHz. There's however other SDRs available, albeit at typically ten times the price.

Comment: Ok, supposing that an attacker has this expensive device, can he eavesdrop bluetooth communication?

Comment: This question is way too broad as is. Without providing the BT version, this question can't be answered. An answer I made [to another question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/200889/165253) gives much more detail because the question gave enough information to determine BT version. It also links to related questions and answers that might be useful. Without more info, the answer could be anything from "not secure at all" to "quite secure". BT LE 4.2 is secure, at least.

Comment: Also, even if you do use a secure version with good encryption, _audio_ transmissions are not always very secure due to compression. It's even possible to extract individual phrases from an encrypted conversation given only the bitrate, as the bitrate varies due to compression of the original waveform.