# What algorithms are used in Bluetooth Secure Simple Pairing LE for authentication, key generation and encryption?

Tags: cryptography, bluetooth

From [another question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116027/difference-between-secure-simple-pairing-and-secure-connections-in-bluetooth/140679#140679) in SO, I got to know a lot about authentication, key generation and encryption algorithms available in Bluetooth BR/EDR:

[image]

I also read the official specification, and it says that LE Secure Connections and BR/EDR Secure Connections are functionally equal. However, I didn't manage to find a word about what algorithms are used in Bluetooth Secure Simple Pairing LE for authentication, key generation and encryption. I dig through the docs, but I didn't find the answer.

I found somewhere online that SSP in LE uses AES-CCM for encryption (is it true for sure?), so the analogous table for Bluetooth LE should look like the one below, right?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From [NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-121/sp800_121_r2_draft.pdf), updated October 2016.

[image: en Key Differences Between Bluetooth BR/EDR and Low Energy]

Comment: The table may be missleading. Note that AES-CCM for BR/EDR is optinal.